# Display a div for a particular element in AngularJS's ng-repeat loop

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have the below HTML code with a div which has AngularJS's ng-repeat.
What I want to do is show the div which says "You have already voted for this review" only for the that particular element for which the div[id="arrow_up"] is clicked.This code displays the div "You have ...." for all elements of the loop once clicked.
Also the requirement is that this div should go away after 5 seconds interval.

```
    <div  class="col-xs-4"  ng-repeat="review in date_reviews track by $index">
         <div id="arrow_up" class="arrow-up" ng-mouseover="message_up = true" ng-mouseleave="message_up= false" ng-click="saveVote(review[0].review_id,1,$index);" ng-class="{vote_capture_top:voted_up && $index == selectedIndex}"></div>
         <div ng-show = "voted_msg_up" ng-class="{message:$index == selectedIndex}"> You have already voted for this review</div>
         <div class="message" ng-show="message_up">This review is helpful.</div>
    </div>
```

Below is the saveVote function from the controller.

```
$scope.saveVote = function(review_id,type,index){
            console.log(review_id)
            email = $cookies.email;
            console.log(type)
            console.log(index)
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/saveVote',
                data : {
                        "review_id" : review_id,
                        "vote_type" : type,
                        "emailId" : $cookies.email,
                },
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
                // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
                }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                   $scope.selectedIndex = index;    
                   if(data == "already_voted"){
                    $scope.voted_up = false;
                    $scope.voted_down = false;
                    $scope.isDisabled = true;
                    if(type == 1) {

                        $scope.voted_msg_up = true;
                        $scope.voted_msg_down = false;
                         console.log($scope.voted_msg_up)
                    console.log($scope.voted_msg_down)
                    }else {
                        $scope.voted_msg_up = false;
                        $scope.voted_msg_down = true;
                    }

                   } else if(data == "success") {

                    if(type == 1) {
                        $scope.voted_up= true    
                    }else {
                        $scope.voted_down = true    
                    }
                   }
                }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.status = status;
                    $window.alert("error")
                }); 
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the div tag to the following and it making div appear for that particular element worked.

```
 <div ng-show = "voted_msg_up && $index == selectedIndex"> You have already voted for this  review</div>
```

But how to remove the div after 5seconds is still not known.